# How add wavefront file(.obj) to surface3d qml?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qml, wavefront

I wanna add a obj file(wavefront format) as a point(by a position) in **surface3d in qml**
but i dont know how i do it!

i found some solutions but they have some problems, for example i just want use qml , but they use c++ and QCustomItem .

i tried to use it in sactter3d with new mesh (just training with that) but it couldnt work:

```
    mesh:Abstract3DSeries.MeshUserDefined
    userDefinedMesh:Mesh{
        source: "wfObj.obj"
    }
```

it was just a training , my main queston is adding waveFront to surface3d qml.

thx for helping .

Comment: If you are using Qt3D, then `SceneLoader` is what you need to load .obj/.mtl files and render them with Qt3D: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-sceneloader.html

Comment: No im not using qt3d , as i said i use surface3d , i just want use surface3d and add a custome waveform as a point in surface3d qml type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i added my CustomItem in qml.
at first i created a **Custom3DItem** :

```
Custom3DItem
{
    id:c3i
    meshFile: qsTr(":/Items/oilrig.obj")
    position: Qt.vector3d(35,150,35)
    textureFile: qsTr(":/Items/redPng.png")
    visible: true
    scaling: Qt.vector3d( 0.25 , 0.25 , 0.25 )
}
```

then i wanted add it to my Surface3d(id:mySurface) , for doing it i needed add it by a method ,so i used an **Item** and **component.onCompleted**:

```
Component.onCompleted: mySurface.addCustomItem(c3i);
```